# Difference data between adjacent rows

Tags: mysql, select, cursors

I have a table (called `Visits`) with `ReqTime DATETIME NOT NULL` column AND `Duration INT UNSIGNED` column.

Duration should be set to the difference of `ReqTime` for two adjacent rows. But `Duration` is not set when inserting new rows to the table. It is calculated afterward.

I calculate the "duration" of a row R as the interval (in seconds) between R.ReqTime and N.ReqTime where N is the next row (first row, inserted later the current row).

Thus for each row R (except of the last inserted row, as for it N is undefined) we have `Duration` value.

See pseudocode for updating the table with the correct `Duration` value (where R is the current row and N is the next (inserted later) row):

```
UPDATE Visits SET R.Duration=TIMEDIFF(N.ReqTime, R.ReqTime) WHERE R.Duration IS NULL
```

Should I use cursors to solve this problem? Or are MIN/MAX/ORDER BY fine?

I am not yet comfortable with cursors.

MySQL 5.

Comment: Search about emulating the LAG function with user variables.

Comment: Don't bother learning CURSORS; in over 30 years as a database applications developer I have never once used one, except by way of demonstrating that they were unnecessary and non-performant.

Answer (score 4):

This SQL works fine in SQL Server (with appropriate syntax modifications):

```
UPDATE Visits
SET Duration = TimeDiff(
         ( SELECT ReqTime FROM Visits N WHERE n.ReqTime > R.ReqTime ORDER BY ReqTime LIMIT 1)
        ,R.ReqTime
    )
FROM Visits R ;
```

Unfortunately, the syntax hits a limitation of MySQL that an updated table cannot be referenced (again) in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE`. A common workaround is to rewrite with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Visits R
  JOIN Visits U
    ON U.pk = ( SELECT N.pk                 -- the Primary Key of the table 
                FROM Visits N 
                WHERE N.ReqTime > R.ReqTime 
                ORDER BY N.ReqTime 
                LIMIT 1
              )
SET R.Duration = TimeDiff(U.ReqTime, R.ReqTime) ;
```

Comment: @user46591: Typo corrected for *Timeiff*.

Comment: That would be more efficient with the "window" functions available in DBs like MS SQL Server and postgres, specifically LAG(). This can be emulated in mySQL though (see this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11316349/114292) so might be worth considering.

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'R' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @porton, did you try the second update statement?

Comment: @ypercube: Still learning about LATERAL JOIN (ie OUTER APPLY); would that simplify the syntax of the amended query when available?